# How to send Uncaught exceptions Crash reports to Google Analytics from iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I want to send the 
uncaught exceptions crash reports to google analytics from iOS.I tried the 
below code but the crash report is not displaying in google 
analytics.Can anyone please provide me some information regarding this?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google 
Analytics.
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 
seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;

// Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];


// Initialize tracker. Replace with your tracking ID.
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXXXXXX-Y"];
(Used my app tracking Id)
 return YES;}


 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : GAITrackedViewController
@end
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
@interface ViewController ()
{
  UIButton *btn;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.screenName = @"About Screen";

btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame=CGRectMake(100, 100, 150, 50);
[btn setTitle:@"Send" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(function) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];

}
  -(void)function
  {
   NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"", nil];
   NSLog(@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:2]);
   }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: same issue here. Are you using any other sdk for crash reporting?

Comment: stop running the app and open the app in simulator .Click on button then it'll crash.Again open the app,then crash report will go to google analytics.

Comment: Does your issue solved? Are you getting crashes in analytics?

Comment: Yeah.I got the crashes in google analytics..

Comment: You can use crashlytics

Comment: Anybody able to resolve it. I can't see the crashes. 

Similar question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591995/how-to-track-google-analytics-uncaught-exceptions

Comment: My app got crashed but no error reports in google analytics under behavior -> Crashes and Exceptions